# Comments Box On My WordPress Site's Post Page Has Disappeared

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming, blogs

How do I make my comment display on my post page. FYI, I deactivated the comment box on my WordPress site's pages and allowed it on the  post pages. However, I've soon noticed that the  comment box do no longer show on my post pages. What do I do??

Answer (score 1):

I also decided recently to disable comments on the pages of my blog but leave it for the posts.

I simply opened **Page Template** (page.php) and commented out comment code like this:

```
<?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```